# SPD 2013 - Approval Workflow RegisterInterestInList Error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow, designer-workflow

I publish a SharePoint 2013 approval workflow.

When I started a workflow it is working properly because I am site collection admin but when other users started a workflow it gives and error like that.

```
Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled in less than one minute. Details of last request: HTTP Unauthorized to https://xxx.domain.com.tr/workspaces/7502/_api/SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowSubscriptionService.Current/RegisterInterestInList?listId='69f4352f-f011-49cf-8705-25a1cbc901fe'&eventName='ItemUpdated' Correlation Id: ae393772-cef9-8d44-abdf-e7a9eed8db64 Instance Id: c7f30538-167d-43ea-b5e4-4badec44a676

Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.
```

Please let me know  if any one come across the similar issue and found solution .

Answer (score 1):

This issue may be caused by insufficient users’ permissions. Please check whether users have enough permissions.

You could try to create a workflow with elevated permissions.

References:

[Create a workflow with elevated permissions by using the SharePoint workflow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-workflo)

[SharePoint 2013 workflow app step and app permissions](http://www.benprins.net/2017/01/02/sharepoint-2013-workflow-app-step-and-app-permissions/)

Comment: Thank you for your help. We are using security group to manage permissions and I recognized that SharePoint Active Directory Import is not configured correctly. Thus, there were missing security groups.It can be related.

Comment: Thank you for your sharing.